# Proper HTML, CSS, JS, PHP File Organizing?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, xampp

I really dont know what to ask for this one. I am drowned with issues and really couldn't process properly so pardon me if this question would be not specific. I will try my best to describe the problem, it might be even simple to answer for you guys but here it goes.

So I am creating a website and is beginning to start php and database on it. And then it hit me, I have to save php files inside the htcdocs folder. And by doing so, 1. Do I move my entire root folder inside it so that I dont have to bother moving? And another question came, I read that I need to change .html extensions to .php for those documents that use php, is that so? Because it messed up my website.

I couldnt use my CSS properly even though I made sure to really check if the path is correct, they are.
If renaming .html to .php is a step, then should I have used .php right from the start?

I really am overwhelmed right now. I hope I was clear. Thank you!

Comment: Did you install a Web Server? Apache / IIS/ Something similiar? Or are you launching the pages from the file manager i.e. does the url start `file:///` or `http://`

Comment: `.html` files will not process PHP (unless you tell your server to do so), so yes, rename them. Need more info/code for your css problem. Also https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.general.php

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am using Xampp

Comment: So the browser address bar starts `http://`?

Comment: @brombeer Is it better if I add php when I know that every thing html related is finished?

Comment: Start right with php, maybe take a look at a template engine for php for the html part

Comment: If yo know you are going to want to use PHP always start with a `.php` extension. HTML is `.php` file is also sent to the browser

Comment: @RiggsFolly No it does not start with `http://`, it starts with localhost.

Comment: OK, with localhost, `http://localhost` is implied. Sorry yo go on, but you would not be the first person to expect PHP to work without a web server :)

Answer (score 1):

You should place your project root folder in htdocs folder in case of Xampp or www folder in case of WAMP etc. You can write both HTML and PHP in .php files . However you cannot do the same if you use .html files. So you can use .php files from the beginning. If you want to change how the apache server handles your request you can use .htaccess file to modify that.

Comment: Thank you. So it is good practice to save the root directly inside it. Mentioning my css problem, does saving the root folder affect how the php files link to css? If it doesn't then I may have just messed up something accidentally.

Comment: @AaronAncheta PHP files will work same way as the html files. The only difference will be that when you will save a file with .php extension then inside the file whenever you will use  the PHP tag <?php    ?>. The PHP interpreter will parse the code between these tags and will substitute it dynamically during compile time.  for html you can write it any where outside the PHP tags ..for using html between the PHP tag you will have to include it along with echo "<p> Hello There </p>"; like that. This is a simple example .You can always embed html code inside PHP

Comment: Thank you so much. It is clearer to me now. :)